# Using another class in a class when developing a chess program (Java)

Tags: java

I am currently writing a chess program, and I am having an issue using the Piece class in a Board class.

So, my basic idea is as follows:

I created a Piece class that contains a x,y coordinate, color, and the empty status. Then, I created a Board class which will generate a 2D Piece array to generate a chessboard-like structure.

So, for example, I want to do something like

```
Board board = new Board(); // This will generate a 2D array of Piece class.
Rook r1 = new Rook(0, 0, BLACK, false); //subclass of Piece
board.movePiece(r1, 1, 1); // moves r1 to 1,1
```

But the problem that I am having is,

```
public class Board {

    private static final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 8;
    private static final int NUM_OF_COLS = 8;

    private static final Piece[][] board = generateBoard();

    private static Piece[][] generateBoard() {

        Piece[][] board = new Piece[NUM_OF_ROWS][NUM_OF_COLS];

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ROWS; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < NUM_OF_COLS; j++) {

                board[i][j] = new Piece(i, j, null, true);

            }
        }

        return board;

    }
}
```

If I do this to auto-generate a 2D-Piece-array whenever I instantiate a new Board, it gives me an error that I cannot instantiate new Piece(); since it's an abstract class. If I extend the Piece class, it becomes more complicated and does not actually make sense design wise to make the Board extend a Piece.

How could I fix this design-wise and code-wise? What is the thing that I am missing right now? I will also put my code for the Piece class below.

```
public abstract class Piece {

    int x, y;
    Players color;
    boolean isEmpty;

    Piece(int x, int y, Players color, boolean isEmpty){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
        this.isEmpty= isEmpty;
    }

    public abstract boolean isValidLocation(Tile[][] board, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY);

    Players getColor() {
        return color;
    }

}
```

Comment: You won't instantiate `Piece`; you would instead instantiate its concrete descendants, like `Rook`, `Pawn`, `Knight`, `King` or `Queen`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you separate the logic conserning a valid place for a Piece. Keep the piece class just for types and implement movements for different pieces with Strategy pattern for example.